# HTML table width align="center" is not center aligned when unhidden (only Firefox)

Tags: html

Here is a demo of the problem:

```
<table id="x" align="center">
<tr>
<td>
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('x').style.display='none';; document.getElementById('y').style.display='block';" value="1" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>


<table id="y" style="display:none;" align="center">
<tr>
<td>
2
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

When the button is pressed, the table with "2" is not center aligned! Why?

This problem only happens on Firefox, on IE it works.

Comment: Never, ever use IE as a reference for how things should work.

Comment: @Rob Unless it's IE11, because as of this writing it works better than Chrome, so... yeah.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Absolutely false and IE11, like all IEs, is inept at best and years behind any other in modern standards support. See HTML5test and CSS3test for first examples. Then others for advanced examples. And here IE11 will sit for at least a year while all others move the web forward every 6-8 weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `block` is not the correct `display` value for a table.

Either set it to `.style.display = 'table'`... or better still `.style.display = ''` to let the browser default take over.

Also `align="center"` is incorrect - prefer `margin:0 auto` in CSS instead.